# How to get the author of an Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I got an Java/Kotlin app built with Gradle and compressed with a .zip extension that was developed in Android Studio. After extracting, how can I find out the author of an existing project who created it?

Comment: Check if the archive contains some kind of source code versioning info, e.g. a `.git` or `.svn` folder. That would probably contain some identifying info.

Comment: There are no .git and .svn files in the archive. Build.gradle file contains the version, but here the code does not contain information about the author. In this case, it is not possible to find out the author/creator at all?

Comment: There is no surefire way to find this information. Perhaps the developer deliberately removed any identifying info? I would suggest that you look for signs of a github repository or similar, e.g. in the gradle files, or google the name of the project and see if you can find it hosted somewhere.

Comment: It wasn't uploaded on Github. In which Gradle file should I find any information about author/creator?

Comment: It's completely optional information, so you might find nothing. There are most probably only one or two gradle-related configuration files. Look through those.